# Exceptions thrown inside middleware are not being logged

Tags: laravel

I'm throwing an exception like this:

```
use \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;


class MyMiddleware {
   public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        ....
        throw new AuthorizationException();

    }
}
```

The exception is succcessfully thrown as expected but it doesn't hit the laravel.log file, nor it doesn't hit Exceptions/Handle.php

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: `AuthorizationException`s are not "reported" (logged)

Comment: @lagbox is right: see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php -- it is part of $internalDontReport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthorizationExceptions are not reported. One way to do what you want is to create a new exception. Something like this should work:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
       if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
           return (new CustomAuthorizationException)->render();
       }
    }
}
```